# How to get the name of the executed controller in $app->after in phalcon

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, phalcon, middleware

How to get the name of the executed controller in $app->after

In Phalcon PHP framework.

```
<?php 

class Micro extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Micro
{

  public function init()
  {

    $this->after(function() {

      // print the name of the executed controller here

    });

  }

}

?>
```

Comment: `Micro` with controllers? :o

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that's the best place for this, but you can get the last dispatched controller using:

```
$di =  Phalcon\DI::getDefault();
$dispatcher = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();
$dispatcher->setDI($di);
$name = $dispatcher->getControllerName();
```

For more info, check the docs [here](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Dispatcher.html).